# Accepted arguments value in hook functions

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, actions

Let's say I have the following hook function:

```
function my_function() {
  $post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';
  if( !isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] ) )
    $_REQUEST['mode'] = ( $post_type == 'my_post_type' ) ? 'excerpt' : 'list';
}
```

`add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'my_function', 10, 1 );`

The fourth argument is (from WP Codex):

> (int) (optional) The number of arguments the hooked function accepts.
>   In WordPress 1.5.1+, hooked functions can take extra arguments that
>   are set when the matching do_action() or apply_filters() call is run.
>   For example, the action comment_id_not_found will pass any functions
>   that hook onto it the ID of the requested comment.
>
> ```
> Default: 1
> ```

The default value is 1, however I do not pass any arguments to the hook function.

Should I add an action like that?

`add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'my_function', 10, 0 );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted arguments value is used by WordPress as `$length` argument for [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) when performing the action.

It means that, yes, if you pass `0` no argument will be passed to your callback.

However, you should care of that only if your function acts differently if an argument is passed or not.

A function like the one in OP, is defined without any argument, nor any function like [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) or [`func_get_arg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) is used in it, so it means that **you can pass any number of arguments to that function, but it will not change its behaviour**.

For that reason you can just ignore the 4th argument of `add_action` like so:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'my_function', 10 );
```

also consider that 10 is default priority, so previous line has same effect of

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'my_function' );
```

It's not worse nor better from a code quality point of view, avoid to pass irrelevant arguments just saves you to type some chars.